# How to set range to terraform schema.schema field?

Tags: go, schema, terraform

I have a number_of_servers field in schema.schema and I need to set a range to it. Is there any way to do it?

```
Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
        "number_of_servers": {
            Type:     schema.TypeString,
            Required: true,
            Range: 1-5,
        },
```

Comment: The `schema.Schema` type has no `Range` field, and I'm not sure what `-4` should mean for a "range" on a string value. Are you possibly looking for `Schema.ValidateFunc `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking validation functions are meant to validate any configs (possibly combined with variables). These run as part of `terraform plan`, `terraform apply` and `terraform destroy`. The user can also trigger explicit validation via `terraform validate` which is commonly used in CI.

Assuming that "Range" is meant to limit minimum & maximum number of characters in a given string you can use [`StringLenBetween` from the validation package](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/master/helper/validation/validation.go#L93).

```
Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
    "number_of_servers": {
        Type:     schema.TypeString,
        Required: true,
        ValidateFunc: validation.StringLenBetween(1, 5),
    },
```

You can see it being used in practice here:
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/46bff11/aws/resource_aws_cloudwatch_event_target.go#L71-L75